# Subjunctive future form -- how and when to use it? Example with "I think I'll go there"?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, futuro

What's the correct way to say `"I think I'll go there"`?

I should use subjunctive form, correct? And the future tense of it, not present?

Therefore it'd be:

> Creo que **fuere** allí

However, I did a google search and found almost nothing with the word "fuere"

Or should I use 'vaya' in this case instead?

> Creo que **vaya** allí

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The future subjunctive basically isn't used at all in modern Spanish.

Even when it was used, it would not likely have been used in the instance you gave since it almost always was used in adverbial or adjectival clauses.

But, if you really wanted to use future subjunctive in your example we need to fulfill several things:

1. Begin the sentence in future (that is, *creeré*)
2. Use a verb that causes subjunctive (perhaps negating *creer*)
3. Refer to action that will be simultaneous to or posterior to the action described in 1.

You could end up with a sentence like the following than:

> No creeré que fuere allí.

But this sounds horrible.

In your sentence, you'll notice that even in English you begin with "I think", which is in the present tense.  Thus we'll want to begin the same:

> Creo que …

And the second bit in English, "I'll go there" can be equally well expressed in Spanish as "Voy allí", "voy a ir allí" or "iré allí" (and also will *allí* in front).  All either explicitly or implicitly indicate future actions.  If you include an adverb that indicates a future time, then even for "voy allí" which is ambiguous otherwise, there is no question we mean future.  So you can say any of the following:

> Creo que voy allí
>   Creo que voy a ir allí
>   Creo que iré allí

Comment: okay, but why not `Creo que vaya allí`?

Comment: @nylypej there is no reason to use the subjunctive. You're affirming the fact that you will go, which is textbook indicative. If you said you *don't* believe, then you can use subjunctive

Comment: how would it be translated or what would it imply if I said `Creo que vaya allí`?

Comment: `If you said you don't believe, then you can use subjunctive` --> why? I may be sure 100% that I won't go

Comment: @nylypej if you are sure that you won't go, then you put the negative in the second clause, and you are affirming that you won't go. That's different from disbelieving (wholely or in part) that you won't. *Creo que vaya* is ungrammatical.

Comment: How could `Creo que vaya ....` be ungrammatical if, for instance, `Creo que sea berdad` is grammatical and in terms of grammar these are absolutely identical?

Comment: @nylypej *creo que sea verdad* is not grammatical...  There may be some dialect that has adopted that, burning Standard Spanish it must be *creo que es verdad*

Comment: `creo que sea verdad` has been heard from a native speaker from Spain, in one of his lessons -- he's a teacher

Comment: @nylypej I'm a professor of Spanish in my day job and my area of focus is Spain. *Creo que [subj]* is not standard canonical Spanish. You may hear it but you will also hear *habían dos personas* from native speakers...

Comment: And I'm the professor of Spanish

Comment: Para los hablantes nativos de inglés a veces el uso de los verbos como ‘to think’ puede tener un matiz de incertidumbre, depende del contexto. Creo que eso es una de las razones por la que surge la confusión sobre el subjuntivo. Pero tienen razón los que han respondido que ‘creo que + subjuntivo’ es incorrecto.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example there isn’t a need for any subjunctive, just:

> Creo que voy a ir para allí.

or

> Pienso que iré allí.

Among other variants.

It’s the *lack* of belief that can trigger the subjunctive:

> No creo que vaya a ir para allí.

Or if we’re specifically trying to use **fuere** I suppose:

> No creo que yo fuere para allí.

could work, it’s at least very uncommon and probably debateable correctness wise.

Some definitely legit uses of **fuere** that you’ll see from time to time:

> A dónde usted fuere, haga lo que usted viere.
>   - To wherever you may go, do as however you may see. (When in Rome, do as the Romans do.)
>
> Sea lo que fuere. 
>   - Be that as it may. / Whatever the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

Fuera (not fuere) would be the subjunctive of *ser*. For example, "si fuera yo tú" (*if I were you*).

What you want to say is, "Creo que me vaya por allá" (*I think that I'll go there*).

Comment: *fuere* is a valid subjunctive form — it's the future.  *fuera* is one of the past subjunctives.

Comment: "Creo que me vaya por allá" does not seem valid Spanish. Maybe you would like to fix your answer?

Comment: @Joseph Your sentence ‘creo que me vaya...’ isn’t grammatically correct, for example see under ‘Doubt’ https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/spanish/spanish-ii/subjunctive-mood-ii/subjunctive-indicators